# Multi Class Classification predictions when you know each class makes up a specific portion of the test data

Tags: machine-learning, classification, prediction

I'm trying to figure out the best way to incorporate additional information into my predicted solution for a multi class classification problem. Here's the scenario.

There are 10 classes, 1-10. There is a training data set with features and the correct class label, and a testing data set for which I have the features but no class labels

The additional information I have is how many records in the test data have each class label. For example, I know Class 1 makes up 8% of the test data, Class 2 makes up 14% of the test data, etc. If it matters to the solution, I also know this distribution is different than the distribution of the training data (e.g Class 1 makes up 11% of the training data).

A perfect model built on the training data would correctly identify each record in the test data, and therefore predict that 8% of the test data is Class 1. I have a model (cross validated XGBoost, which is less than **perfect**) and a predicted probability that each record belongs to each class.

Now I have two pieces of information

1. Predictions for each record in the test data
2. The correct percent of the test data made up by each class.

**How can I use the second piece of information to make my predictions more accurate?**

I'd like to build it into the training process somehow or manipulate the predictions after the fact to reflect this information.

Comment: You should be able to do this with Bayes' Theorem. There is a standard solution to this with, for example, Linear Discriminant Analysis and MNL. However, I have no idea what XGBoost is, so am not game to post a more precise answer.

Comment: @Tim would the procedure you mention be applied after the original predictions are made, or as part of a model building process? I am not too familiar with LDA or MNL, so if you have resources to help me understand how to apply them to the problem at hand that would be great.

Comment: The basic mechanics of both LDA and MNL are that once you have fit the model, you can change a specific set of parameters that address the prior probability of class membership in the predictions. Let me spend a few minutes of contemplation and see if I can figure out the general solution.

Comment: See equation (4) in https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d6d2/2681ee7e40a1817d03c730d5c2098ef031ae.pdf

Comment: @Tim, thanks for the link to the paper.Implementing this helped me very minimally, but there was a tiny bit of lift. It's basically exactly what I need, except, when I adjust my predictions I still have total prediction for class x = 500 observations and I know class x has 600 observations in the test set. I suppose any further manipulation beyond the Bayes formula given would result in a loss of classification accuracy. Perhaps iterating through until reaching a steady state would be a good solution.

Comment: @Tim the other option I am now considering is assigning weights to the training examples based on their class portion of the test data. Do you have any thoughts on the validity of this approach?

Comment: Mmm... I would have thoguht that (4) was an exact solution, so I I am surprised. The weighting approach should make the predictions look more sensible, but the effective sample size of your model reduces. This will potentially be a problem if your model has any automated variable selection in it. I would be working harder to find out what went wrong with (4). But, as mentioned at the beginning, XGBoost is outside my expertise.